# Buber's "It-world": original German?

Tags: german-philosophy, translation

Does anyone know how what Kaufman renders as "It-world" (in "I and Thou") appears in the original German?

Comment: It seems to me that "the world of *It*" is the transaltion of the German : "der Es-Welt".

Answer (score 0):

Probably Buber says "dingliche Welt (it-world)". The German term *dinglich* is the adjective to the noun *Ding (thing)*.

But to be sure you must quote the precise passage from your English edition.

Comment: Searching briefly I got die dingliche Welt, dem „Es“  but I don't have either the German or the English with me at this point to confirm.